# Code editor control VB .NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, vsto, code-editor

Does anyone know if the code editor used by VSTO IDE is available to use in my own projects?

I need to use a code editor in my project. I Googled to try to find one, but I found several third party solutions (pay or free) but they don't fit my needs.

In same way as Webbrowser control, is the "sourcecodeeditor" control of VSTO available to use as a project component?

Comment: No, it's a very unusual case that you would need to write your own version of Visual Studio, and Microsoft would prefer that you didn't. We might be able to suggest a third-party alternative that would fit your requirements if you could be more specific about what they are.

Comment: We are developing a plugin system based on dynamic code. This is a base program where we can add new source code stored in a database, and this base program loads, compile and creates all objects from this code and prepare them for use.

The problem is the source code editor. In a first version we used a third party source code editor, but the implementation was very hard and the maintenance pretty complicated.

Exists the class "MSVSTOSourceCodeEditor"? This is the question.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> In same way as Webbrowser control, is the "sourcecodeeditor" control of VSTO available to use as a project component?
>
> [. . .]
>
> Exists the class "MSVSTOSourceCodeEditor"? This is the question. Thanks

**Unfortunately, no.** Microsoft doesn't allow you to subclass its source code editor, nor do they provide a version for use in your own projects. As I mentioned before, they don't really want to encourage you to rewrite Visual Studio. They'd prefer that you bought it instead!

Have you considered creating a plug-in or extension for Visual Studio instead? It's a little bit different way of going about it, but it just might work for you. Your developers might find it more convenient since they won't have to switch back and forth between two programs.

If you're really set on rolling your own custom solution, probably the best thing to do is check the source code for some of the open-source, Visual Studio-style IDEs, and see how they've written the code editor:

- [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/)
- [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/opensource/sd/)
- [KDevelop](http://www.kdevelop.org/)